# How to extract the values of a,b of a string in the form of ?(a*p+b)/p**2

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Given a string in python in the form of:

```
(a*p+b)/p**2
```

That always follows this format, for instance `(3.02*p+4.12)/p**2` I would like to extract a and b, which in the example is `3.02` and `4.12`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.split` and `str.strip`:

```
>>> s = '(3.02+4.12*p)/p**2'
>>> s.strip('(').split('*')[0].split('+')
['3.02', '4.12']
```

**Update**:

You could use regex if the pattern gets too complex:

```
>>> s = '(3.02*p+4.12)/p**2'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)\*p\+(\d+.\d+)', s)[0]
('3.02', '4.12')
```

Comment: Sorry It is '(3.02p+4.12*)/p**2'

Comment: Sorry it does not work because it is not 3.02p but 3.02*p

Comment: @NancyM.Sheehan Updated

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !